# Why does the "this" keyword refer to the subclass too?

Tags: java, oop, this

In the following scenario, `Main.registerEvents(Listener)` is part of an event system of a game API.
Let's say it should register any method with the `@EventHandler` annotation.

```
public abstract class Spell implements Listener {
    protected Spell() {
        Main.getInstance().registerEvents(this);
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void onMove(PlayerMoveEvent event) {

    }
}
```

---

```
public class Fireball extends Spell {
    @EventHandler
    public void onChat(PlayerChatEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Generally speaking, since `this` refers to the current instance, how is it possible that `Fireball.onChat(PlayerChatEvent)` is registered too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Generally speaking, since this refers to the current instance, how is it possible that Fireball.onChat(PlayerChatEvent) is registered too?

Because when you're constructing an instance of `Fireball`, `this` refers to the `Fireball` being constructed at execution time. The *compile-time* type of `this` is `Spell`, but if you print out `this.getClass()` (even within the `Spell` constructor) it will show `Fireball`.

Therefore if `registerEvents` is looking at the execution-time type of the object and finding event handlers with reflection, it will see `onChat`.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the implementation of the API, I can only guess.

In order to get annotations, one must first get the applicable class, using `Object.getClass()`. This is polymorphic so it returns `Fireball.class`, so then when the annotations are reflectively searched for, both those found in `Fireball` and those found in `Spell` are found.

Answer (score 0):

`Fireball.onChat(PlayerChatEvent)` is registered too because you use the `super()`, which is calling the constructor of the superclass.

`this` is always referencing the instance of the class, from where it is invocated.

Due to the equivalence of a non existent constructor and the one you used in the Fireball class, you should be able to omit the Fireball constructor with no impact on the result.

So finally every `@EventHandler` annotated method in every subclass of spell is registered.